# Diagonal Random Walk

Tags: binomial-distribution

Let (Sn,Tn) denote the position after n steps of a random walk on the lattice points of a plane with integer coordinates, starting from (S0,T0)=(0,0). Suppose Sn+1=Sn±1 and Tn+1=Tn±1 where signs are picked by two independent tosses of a fair coin, independently at each step. I have to find four things:

For c>0 (I don't understand what c is in this context), what is the limit as n→∞ of the probability that (Sn,Tn) is inside the square with corners at (±c(n−−√),±c(n−−√). (I've drawn this on a x−y plane, but I don't know how to go further)

If Rn=(Sn)2+(Tn)2−−−−−−−−−−−√, what is the distance from the origin. Find E(R2n)

If pn denotes the probability that the random walk is at (0,0) after n steps, what is p3? And finally, show that p2nm is equivalent to cm as m→∞ for a constant c. What is that c?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, consider a square $A$ with corners $(\pm c\sqrt(n), \pm c \sqrt(n))$.
As $\{(S_n, T_n) \in A\} \Leftrightarrow \{ S_n \in [-c\sqrt{n}, c\sqrt{n}] \text{ and } T_n \in [-c\sqrt{n}, c\sqrt{n}]\}$ and as $S_n$ and $T_n$ are independent variables you can compute $P(A)$ quite easily using binomial distribution.

Let's call $R_n = \frac{T_n + n}{2}$ the number of times the point went right, such that $R_n \sim \mathcal{B}(n, 0.5)$ which can be approximated by a $\mathcal{N}(\frac{n}{2}, \sigma^2 = \frac{n}{4})$. Then, for large $n$, as $T_n = 2R_n - n$, you have the approximation : 
$$T_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 = n)$$
so $P(T_n \in [-c\sqrt{n}, c\sqrt{n}]) \to \Phi(c) - \Phi(-c) = 2\Phi(c)-1$. Thus, with the same reasoning applied to $S_n$, you get that $$P((S_n, T_n) \in A) \to_{n\to\infty} (2\Phi(c)-1)^2$$

For the expectation, you have that $E(T_n^2) = E(S_n^2) = \frac{n}{4}$ such that $E(R_n) = \frac{n}{2}$

Finally, $P(T_n = S_n=0) = P(T_n = 0)^2 = P(R_n = \frac{n}{2})^2$ this is $0$ if $n$ is odd and otherwise if $ n = 2m$ this is 
$$P(T_{2m} = S_{2m}=0) = ({{2m} \choose m}  \frac{1}{2^n})^2  $$

Using for example [Striling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), you get that this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2\pi}m$ when $m$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much! If lets say, I were to do this same problem again, but instead of diagonal moves, each step there is an equal probability of going up down left or right, even though the variables are not independent here, it seems like they are roughly independent for a sufficiently large n. Also I think it would be safe to assume that the error of approximation would tend to zero as n goes to infinity. What would this change in the answer?

Comment: Please be careful in providing answers to self-study questions like this.  
[Our policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) is to only 
provide hints to help get the OP unstuck.